# Who to put methods in a array to use?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I wonder if there is some way to create a methods array to make the call this array in place of the method in the example below I create an array that stores user objects in this class there is the getName method, I would like to call this method by an array, as follows the example is an example:

```
public class JavaApplication48 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        User[] u = new User[] {new User ("1", "John"), new User ("2", "Tereza"), new User ("3", "Tobias")};

        //there put the methods .getId() and .getName in a array, i dont know who

        //...

        //and concatenating the users array with methods array like this
        System.out.println(u[0]ac[1]);
        //to print on the console "John"
        }
}

class User {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public User(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand your question. Try to be more clear.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are asking exactly?

Comment: `System.out.println(u[0].getName());`

Comment: This isn't python, methods aren't (normally) objects.

Comment: I suppose you could conceivably do this with Java 8 but it seems silly.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Do you want to somehow make the methods to be used configurable outside of the program? Otherwise, you can just call `getName()` and `getId()` directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull this off using lambda expressions:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    User[] u = new User[] {new User ("1", "John"), new User ("2", "Tereza"), new User ("3", "Tobias")};
    Function<User, String> f1 = user -> user.getName();
    Function<User, String> f2 = user -> user.getId();
    Function<User, String>[] f = new Function[] { f1, f2 };

    System.out.println(f[0].apply(u[0]));
 }
```

(I don't understand what you want to achieve with this, but this is technically the way to go.)

The functions we declared have a method "apply" declared in their interface, thus the final call as you see in the System.out-line is

```
functionReference.apply(inputObject)
```